# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason I'm getting the invalid hook call error. It's the first time I've used hooks for a new component. I even commented out and/or removed the hooks from the code but it still gave the error. One other thing I can think of is that I am installing this component into the app by giving the direct file path like

```
"dependencies": {
  "br": "file.../br"
}
```

Which according to the docs could happen if there's 2 react versions? I'm not sure if that's the issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BrRelatedSearchCategory from "./bloomreach/br-related-search-category";
import BrRelatedProduct from "./bloomreach/br-related-product";
import {fetchBrSEO} from "../store/bloomreach/bloomreach-seo.actions";
export const baseClass = "sc-br";
const c = prefix(baseClass);

/* Each module can be individually not rendered by passing in the corresponding prop
*  hideRelatedSearches
*  hideRelatedCategories
*  hideRelatedProducts  */

export const BloomreachSEO = ({relatedSearches, relatedCategories, relatedProducts, fetchBrSEO, hideRelatedSearches, hideRelatedCategories, hideRelatedProducts}) => {
  // Fetch bloomreach data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBrSEO();
  }, [])

  const RelatedSearches = ({relatedSearches, hideRelatedSearches}) => {
    if (relatedSearches && !hideRelatedSearches) {
      return (
        <div className={c("related-searches")}>
          <b className={c("related-searches-title")}>Related searches</b>
          <div className={c("related-searches-container")}>
            {relatedSearches.map((relatedSearch) => {
              return (
                <BrRelatedSearchCategory
                  searchOrCategory={relatedSearch}
                  className={"search"}
                />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return null;
  }

  const RelatedCategories = ({relatedCategories, hideRelatedCategories}) => {
    if (relatedCategories && !hideRelatedCategories) {
      return (
        <div className={c("related-categories")}>
          <b className={c("related-categories-title")}>Related categories</b>
          <div className={c("related-categories-container")}>
            {relatedCategories.map((relatedCategory) => {
              return (
                <BrRelatedSearchCategory
                  searchOrCategory={relatedCategory}
                  className={"category"}
                />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return null;
  }

  const RelatedProducts = ({relatedProducts, hideRelatedProducts}) => {
    if (relatedProducts && !hideRelatedProducts) {
      return (
        <div className={c("related-products")}>
          <b className={c("related-products-title")}>Related products</b>
          <div className={c("related-products-container")}>
            {relatedProducts.map((product) => {
              return (
                <BrRelatedProduct
                  relatedProduct={product}
                />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className={c(baseClass)}>
      <RelatedSearches
        relatedSearches={relatedSearches}
        hideRelatedSearches={hideRelatedSearches}
      />
      <RelatedCategories
        relatedCategories={relatedCategories}
        hideRelatedCategories={hideRelatedCategories}
      />
      <RelatedProducts
        relatedProducts={relatedProducts}
        hideRelatedProducts={hideRelatedProducts}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

BloomreachSEO.propTypes = {
  relatedSearches: PropTypes.array,
  relatedCategories: PropTypes.array,
  relatedProducts: PropTypes.array,
  fetchBrSeo: PropTypes.func,
  hideRelatedSearches: PropTypes.bool,
  hideRelatedCategories: PropTypes.bool,
  hideRelatedProducts: PropTypes.bool
};

BloomreachSEO.defaultPops = {
  hideRelatedCategories: false,
  hideRelatedProducts: false,
  hideRelatedSearches: false
}

export default page(
  state => ({
    relatedSearches: state["related-item"],
    relatedCategories: state["related-category"],
    relatedProducts: state["more-results"]
  }),
  {
    fetchBrSEO
  }
)(BloomreachSEO);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like installing my local package by linking directly to it with

```
"dependencies": {
  "br": "file.../br"
}
```

was the issue. The issue was having 2 reacts one from the app and one from my local package itself. I used yalc instead and everything works fine now.